# Update uncommitted data using Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jta

In a transaction, if there's a failure, is it possible to update the uncommitted data and commit instead of rolling back the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. That's not possible, and for very good reasons.

When you get an Exception while flushing the JPA and Hibernate Persistence Context, it's not clear how many entity state transitions have been synchronized, and which state transitions haven't been flushed at all.

Just like an [ACID transaction should be atomic](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/), the JPA Unit of Work (Persistence Context) should be atomic as well.

Trying to break this behavior is a data access Design Smell and tels you that there is a better solution to the original problem that led you to this question.

Comment: Is it better to let the transaction manager rollback the transaction and insert a record to different table for audit trail?

Comment: Well, the transaction being rolled back means there will be no entry in the database redo log, hence the audit log should not mark inexistent database changes. However, if you need to use Event Sourcing, then you can log all commands, no matter whether they succeed or fail. For that, you need to use a separate transaction prior to opening the one with JPA and Hibernate.

Comment: Is there any jta equivalent of propagation - requires_new or how it can be done programmatically?